# How to check ViewBag's property in a cshtml page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I am working on MVC application and I need to check `ViewBag` value on cshtml page, how can I do that?

on Controller.cs:

```
Viewbag.Mode= "EDIT";
```

I need to check the value from `Viewbag.Mode` 
if it is `EDIT` show alert as `EDIT`

I am writing this conditional code in JavaScript, what is the syntax to check Viewbag property in cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get direct access to C# variables in javascript as one is server-side, the other client-side. You need to write the ViewBag value to the HTML output and then interrogate the DOM to find it using javascript. Something like this:

In your CSHTML:

```
@Html.Hidden("Mode", (string)ViewBag.Mode, new { id = "mode" })
```

In jQuery:

```
if ($('#mode').val() == "EDIT") {
    // do something...
}
```

You could also wrap the JS code directly in a C# `if (ViewBag.Mode == "EDIT")` statement in your view, however this is both ugly, and not a good separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple.. just use @Razor syntax in ViewPage

```
@if(ViewBag.Mode=="Edit")
{
 //here you show the alert thing
}
```